# this type of my form and how set in validation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cakephp

```
<form action="" id="contact-form1" name="myForm" novalidate="novalidate"  method="post" class="clearfix" >      
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your name...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your name...')this.value='';" value="Your name..." class="text requiredField contactName" >
                    </fieldset >
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Email</label>    
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your email...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your email...')this.value='';" value="Your email..." class="text requiredField email" >
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Contact</label>  
                        <input type="text" name="contactno" id="contactno" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Contact No...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Contact No...')this.value='';" value="Contact No..." class="text requiredField contactno " >
                    </fieldset> 
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Country" id="Country" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Country...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Country...')this.value='';" value="Country..." class="text requiredField" >
                    </fieldset >
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>State</label>
                        <input type="text" name="State" id="State" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='State...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='State...')this.value='';" value="State..." class="text requiredField " >
                    </fieldset >
                    <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>City</label>
                        <input type="text" name="City" id="City" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='City...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='City...')this.value='';" value="City..." class="text requiredField" >
                    </fieldset >
                    <fieldset class="field-1-1 left">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="30" class="text requiredField" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your message...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your message...')this.value='';" >Your message...</textarea>
                    </fieldset>

                   <fieldset class="field-1-3 left">
                        <label>Enter Code</label><img src="captcha.php"/>
                        <input type="text" name="vercode" id="vercode" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Vercode...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Vercode...')this.value='';" value="Vercode..." class="text requiredField" >
                    </fieldset >

                    <fieldset class="right">
                        <input name="Mysubmitted" id="Mysubmitted" value="SEND" class="button medium" value="submit" type="submit" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="contact_success" id="contact_success" value="Thanks your email has been sent successfully" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: seriously? what are you trying to ask from this?

Comment: I think you start from HTML

Comment: at least try your self and then put the snippet if you get any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add **required** attribute for mandated fields.

```
<input id="sample" name="sample" type="text" required="required" />
```

Use drop list for country.

```
<select name="country">
<option value="">Country...</option>
<option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antigua &amp; Barbuda">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
<option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Austria">Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize">Belize</option>
<option value="Benin">Benin</option>
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
<option value="Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
<option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
<option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
<option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="Chad">Chad</option>
<option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
<option value="Chile">Chile</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
<option value="Congo">Congo</option>
<option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="Cote DIvoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
<option value="Curaco">Curacao</option>
<option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
<option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
<option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland">Finland</option>
<option value="France">France</option>
<option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
<option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
<option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
<option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
<option value="Greece">Greece</option>
<option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
<option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
<option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="Guam">Guam</option>
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
<option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
<option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
<option value="Iran">Iran</option>
<option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
<option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="Israel">Israel</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
<option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
<option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
<option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
<option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Laos">Laos</option>
<option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
<option value="Libya">Libya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macau">Macau</option>
<option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
<option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
<option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali">Mali</option>
<option value="Malta">Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
<option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
<option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
<option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
<option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
<option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
<option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
<option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
<option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
<option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger">Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="Niue">Niue</option>
<option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="Norway">Norway</option>
<option value="Oman">Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
<option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
<option value="Panama">Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru">Peru</option>
<option value="Phillipines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
<option value="Poland">Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
<option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
<option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
<option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
<option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
<option value="Russia">Russia</option>
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
<option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
<option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
<option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
<option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
<option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
<option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
<option value="St Pierre &amp; Miquelon">St Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
<option value="St Vincent &amp; Grenadines">St Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
<option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
<option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
<option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
<option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
<option value="Sao Tome &amp; Principe">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
<option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
<option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
<option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syria">Syria</option>
<option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
<option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
<option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="Togo">Togo</option>
<option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
<option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad &amp; Tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Turks &amp; Caicos Is">Turks &amp; Caicos Is</option>
<option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
<option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
<option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
<option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
<option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
<option value="Wallis &amp; Futana Is">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
<option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
<option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Use javascript to validate on form submit.

```
<form action="" id="contact-form1" name="myForm" novalidate="novalidate"  method="post" class="clearfix" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()">
```

JS:

```
       function ValidateForm() {
           //E-mail address validation   
            var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
            var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
                alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: either the *required* method or the *onsubmit* method can work independently, and it may be better to mention that the first method only works in some of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate it using jQuery's validate plugin use:-

if($("#contact-form1").valid()){

submitForm();

}

Answer (score 0):

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

This script lets you verify numbers and emails.